# Which HEMT (standard transistor) amplifiers are used in superconducting qubit readout chain?

Tags: superconducting-quantum-computing, quantum-control, hardware

The two images below show HEMT amplifiers at the 3-6K stage. All the papers simply mention "standard HEMT amplifiers", but I am not sure what "standard" means. Does anyone know of any specific parts/model numbers that are used for amplification at this stage? Are these amplifiers generally selected for noise performance, or gain performance?

[image: Image of readout chain]
[image: HEMT in readout chain]